# CollectionView Add extra cell "Add more"

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cell, uicollectionviewcell

I have an issue to add extra cell to my collection view
I have change a logic to use data model to fill my cells

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pictures.count + 1
    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("images", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProfileImageCell

        let picture = pictures[indexPath.item] as! Gallery

        print(indexPath.item)

        if indexPath.item == pictures.count {
            cell.image.image = UIImage(named: "ProfilePlusImage")
        } else {
            cell.image.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: picture.fileUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "Placeholder"))
            cell.imageId = picture.id.integerValue
        }

        return cell
    }
```

The issue is in this line I think

> let picture = pictures[indexPath.item] as! Gallery

When I mark it and mark

> cell.image.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: picture.fileUrl),
>   placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "Placeholder"))

It adding extra cell on 11-th place. But other way gives my beyond bounds

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Yes, you should verify that `indexPath.item` is less than `pictures.count` before you use it as an index into `pictures`.  You seem to have the answer.

Comment: @i_am_jorf no still index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]

Comment: Simply move that line inside the `else` statement

Comment: @Paulw11 thank it's working, I spent 2 hours to understand what broken :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("images", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProfileImageCell

    print(indexPath.item)

    if indexPath.item == pictures.count {
        cell.image.image = UIImage(named: "ProfilePlusImage")
    } else {
        let picture = pictures[indexPath.item] as! Gallery

        cell.image.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: picture.fileUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "Placeholder"))
        cell.imageId = picture.id.integerValue
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**It seems that your CollectionView have one section so this code should work**

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return 1
    }
    return pictures.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("images", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProfileImageCell

    let picture = pictures[indexPath.item] as! Gallery

    print(indexPath.item)


    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell.image.image = UIImage(named: "ProfilePlusImage")
    } else {
        cell.image.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: picture.fileUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "Placeholder"))
        cell.imageId = picture.id.integerValue
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: This code would not compile because of standalone `if` statement after `print(indexPath.item)`